# How to get the start address of the current process---Linux

Tags: linux, image, entry-point

Could you guys tell me how to get the start virtual address of the current process on linux? Any systems calls or facilities that would be helpful? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much on the subject. try using pmap followed by the PID

Answer (score 1):

Check what does `objdump` do to get that address. Then run it on `/proc/self/exe` in your own code.

```
% objdump -f /proc/self/exe             

/proc/self/exe:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000402f80
```

Answer (score 1):

How about 'grep'ing the output of lsof?

```
lsof | grep <insert name of the program here>
```